# Github Pages - Organisation site not showing up

Tags: github-pages

I created an organisation (`<orgname>`) on github. In that organisation I added a repo named `<orgname>.github.io`. In that repo, I added an `index.html` and fired up `https://<orgname>.github.io` but I kept getting a `404` status.

Why?

Answer (score 0):

I figured by accident that a `README.md` file is mandatory for Github to host the site. Once a README was added, the site loaded immediately.

If I had followed the tuts in pages.github.com, I wouldn't have wasted time. But I started working on a site from my previous experience and a README seemed not so important.